# Declaration and initialisation of array of strings in java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, data-structures, underscore-java

When we declare an String array in Java

```
String[] obj =new String[10];
```

When we print this it return null value by default

But I want to change this null to empty strings but without using loop

Can someone tell me how can I declare an array with value of empty string

You can use any ds to store strings like arraylist arrays etc but by default value should be empty string not null

Array size is variable and using different arrrays

Comment: Why don't you want to use a loop? What's wrong with a loop?

Comment: Because there many array so I have to use to every array and all array contains different different values

Comment: We can use fill method to solve this problem

Comment: Arrays.fill(obj, "");